# "Clôture" vs "Fermeture" dans la littérature française

Tags: terminology, translation-request, mathematical-french

What is the difference between the two terms "clôture" and "fermeture" in mathematical contexts? For example, in topology, is it more common (or more proper) to say "la clôture de l'ensemble A" or "la fermeture de l'ensemble A"? What about other contexts?

To frame the question properly, my questions are: is there any difference between the two terms? which one is more frequently used? does the usage depend on the context? and is there any rule of thumb?

Comment: The terms that I've seen are *adhérence* and *fermeture*, as in [this article](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhérence_(mathématiques)) in French Wikipedia; I am, however, much more familiar with German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In a topological space the closure of a subset is **almost always** called *adhérence*.
I have never seen *clôture* in place of *adhérence* and I might remember having seen *fermeture*, but that would be in fairly old literature.

2) Algebraic closure is  *clôture algébrique*, and similarly we have *clôture séparable, radicielle, intégrale,...*.

3) The word *fermeture* is used for a relative situation:
For example we might say *la fermeture algébrique de $\mathbb R$ dans $\mathbb C(X)$est $\mathbb C$*, meaning that the set of elements of $\mathbb C(X)$  algebraic over $\mathbb R$ is  $\mathbb C$.
Similarly we may speak of:
  *la fermeture séparable de $k$ dans $K$*, *la fermeture intégrale de $A$ dans $B$*, etc.